# running two processes on the PI

Tags: raspberry-pi2, iot, home-automation

Is it possible to run two processes on the raspberry pi simultaneously?

I would like to start a MQTT server AND run Home Automation webserver (Home-Automation.io) at the same time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A raspberry pi is just like any other Linux computer, it will happily run many processes at the same time.

The only possibly problem would be if 2 processes wanted to use the same network port as a server. Since Home-Automation.io does not appear to run it's own MQTT broker (but it is capable of subscribing to topics published on a broker) there should be no problem running it at the same time.

Comment: Understood. So, if I'm SSHing a PI device, how can I start the home-automation app and the MTQQ server?